# Html5 canvas animation slow on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, canvas

I am developing and arcade game for **Android** and **iOS**.
I have an **animation performance issues** on Galaxy S SL  running Android 2.2.1:
to watch the example :
http://jsfiddle.net/qgWdA/show/
to edit the code :
http://jsfiddle.net/qgWdA/

On a Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.3, the animation is faster but not as good as an iphone 4S runnig iOS 5.1.1.

Is there any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is really slow in ICS and is promised to be optimized better in future Android releases.