# Move html elements positions slow on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, html

I have a huge performance issue on iOS html5 webapp when I modify the position of multiple html elements in CSS. I would like also to move manually my elements. I do not want to use CSS transformation because it is not possible to stop the animation (we are making a highly responsive game).

My example works fine on a desktop browser (chrome, firefox, etc.), on Android. But it is very slow on an iPad 2 and an iPhone 4S (both running iOS 5.1).
Running the html5 code in a Phonegap app is better than directly in the browser but is still slow.

What do you suggest to improve things?
[editable example](http://jsfiddle.net/JLGYY/4/)
[full screen example](http://jsfiddle.net/JLGYY/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  It's not jquery, there's something going on with iOS and moving elements...

Comment: @Kevin Nope. I dropped the project and made something less resource consuming... My conclusion was that html5 is not ready for high performance games.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want something that is not slow, avoid all jQuery call you can.

Here is how I would rewrite (really quickly) your code :

```
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-test');
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.width = 500;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // in this example, the fillstyle is always the same. no need to change it at every loop
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";


var balls = [];
var ballcanvas = [];
var ballctx = [];

// create 30 balls in canvases
var eDivBody = document.getElementById('divbody');
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    balls[i] = {
        x : 250,
        y : 100 + i * 2,
        dx : 3, // direction
    };

    // create the canvas
    var eBall = document.createElement('canvas');
    eBall.id = 'ballcanvas' + i;
    eBall.width = 75;
    eBall.height = 75;
    eDivBody.appendChild(eBall);

    // some css
    // no need for jQuery
    eBall.style.position = "absolute";
    eBall.style.left = balls[i].x + "px";
    eBall.style.top = balls[i].y + "px";
    eBall.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";

    // associate the element to the ball, no need to go threw the DOM after
balls[i].element = eBall;
}


var ball_test = {
    x : 250,
    y : 300,
    dx : 3 // direction
};


function loop(ball_test, balls, canvas, context, ballcanvas, ballctx){
    //change of direction on the sides
    if (ball_test.x > 400 || ball_test.x < 100)
        ball_test.dx *= -1;
    // movement
    ball_test.x += ball_test.dx;

    // the same for balls in canvases
    // never use array.legth in a loop condition. put it in a variable then compare. 
    for (var i = 0, j = balls.length; i < j; i++){
        // balls are following the test ball, no need to re-check the bounds
        // we take the test ball direction
        balls[i].dx =  ball_test.dx;

        //movement   
        balls[i].x += balls[i].dx;
        // change left style - No need for jQuery
        balls[i].element.style.left = balls[i].x + "px";
    }

    // display ball_test
    displayBallTest(ball_test, canvas, context);

    // Prefer the use of requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        loop(ball_test, balls, canvas, context, ballcanvas, ballctx);
    });
};

// no need to recalculate Math.PI * 2 for every loop.
// do it just the first time then use the value
var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

function displayBallTest(ball, canvas, context){
    // clear canvas    
    // you don't need to clear all the canvas, just the zone where you now the ball is.
    // must need some calculation to be the most efficient possible
    context.clearRect(ball.x - 50 , ball.y  - 50, 100, 100);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 40, 0, pi2 );
    context.fill();
};

// start main loop
loop(ball_test, balls, canvas, context, ballcanvas, ballctx);
```

I commented the code but here are what I did :

- totally avoiding jQuery. No need, except maybe for the ready if you choose to not put your script at the end of the content
- using requestAnimationFrame when possible
- avoiding recalculation or reset of values when they are global
  (Math.PI*2 , context.fillStyle ... )
- avoiding the use of .length if for loop condition

But I think your problem come from the fact that you want to move 30 canvas elements instead of drawing theyre content into the main canvas.
iOS is known to be fast when you use Canvas Drawing.
For me, your performance problems will be resolved if you choose to draw on the main canvas instead of moving DOM elements.

Comment: We use 30 canvas because it is very slow on Android to draw multiple items on a main canvas ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557651/html5-canvas-animation-slow-on-android ). We would like the same code base for multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing you can do is cache your selector instead of executing it every time:

```
   // some css            
    $('#ballcanvas' + i).css("position", "absolute");
    $('#ballcanvas' + i).css("left", balls[i].x + "px");
    $('#ballcanvas' + i).css("top", balls[i].y + "px");
    $('#ballcanvas' + i).css("background-color", "#000000");
```

Should be something like:

```
var thisBall = $('#ballcanvas' + i)
thisBall.css("position", "absolute");
... rest of your code ....
```

Aside: Why bother using `document.getElementById`, when you already have Jquery `$`.

Comment: He does not need the selector. $('#ballcanvas' + i) is created just before. He has to act on ballcanvas[i]. BUT it's not the problem since this function just initialize the animation. the problem come after. First of all, the use of `.length` in the loop condition. Downvote because you tell him to use jQuery, when he asks for rapidity. AVOIDING jQuery would have been a good answer.